# Count of occurrences crossing a given time range

Tags: google-sheets

Sorry about the title of this question, I couldn't think of a better way of phrasing it.

I have a column with time ranges in it, i.e.

08:45-17:00

06:00-10:30

09:10-14:30

08:15-16:50

10:15-17:15

15:30-20:10

09:30-13:10

etc.

What I need is a count of those occurrences that cross a comparison time range. For example with a comparison range of 11:00-15:00, the count should include any in the column that:-

(1). has a start time OR end time between 11:00 and 15:00

OR

(2). starts BEFORE 11:00 AND ends AFTER 15:00.

In the examples above the count would be 5.

This formula gives the correct result (0 or 1) for individual entries:

```
=sum(if(or(and(mid(I14,7,5)>"15:00",mid(I14,1,5)<"11:00"),and(mid(I14,1,5)>"11:00",mid(I14,1,5)<"15:00"),and(mid(I14,7,5)>"11:00",mid(I14,7,5)<"15:00")),1,0))
```

There is probably a more elegant way of writing that!

Wrapping an arrayformula around that code doesn't work.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is the GoogleSheets version of Ed's formula (thx Ed)

=arrayformula(counta(filter(H9:H44,or(and(left(H9:H44,5)<="11:00",right(H9:H44,5)>="15:00"),and(left(H9:H44,5)>="11:00",left(H9:H44,5)<="15:00"),and(right(H9:H44,5)<="15:00",right(H9:H44,5)>="11:00")))))

It seems that Filter doesn't like the use of "and" and "or" as it always returns 1 as the result, regardless of the entries.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you want. It uses counta and filter. The '+' are or and the '*' are and. I put the date ranges in A1:A7 so adjust to your range.

```
=arrayformula(COUNTA(FILTER( A:A ,(((right(A:A,5)>"15:00")*(left(A:A,5)<"11:00"))+(((left(A:A,5)>"11:00")*(left(A:A,5)<"15:00")))+(((left(A:A,5)>"11:00")*(LEFT(A:A,5)<"15:00")))+((right(A:A,5)>"11:00")*(RIGHT(A:A,5)<"15:00"))) )))
```